# Finding constraints enforced across multiple tables in oracle

Tags: oracle, constraints, database

I have a database with the following tables EMP, DEPT, CLIENT and PURCHASE. I am using Oracle 11g express edition

I have executed the following SQL statement to find out constraints on table : EMP

```
SELECT * FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'EMP'
```

Is there a way to find out what constraints are currently enforced upon this database across multiple table in one statement?

E.g. EMP AND CLIENT AND etc something like that.

Comment: Seriously?  This is an astonishingly trivial piece of SQL syntax.  Use `OR` (not `AND`): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions004.htm#sthref1935.  Or perhaps `IN` http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions013.htm#i1050801

Comment: Yeah i'm just starting out... sorry I'm not as good as you

Comment: Also funny that you're kind of rude, and still couldn't give any constructive information either, since neither of those work

Comment: Both links work from Chrome.  Perhaps other browsers have difficulties with links that don't have `http:/` in front of them?

Comment: I mean IN nor OR work, not the links.

Comment: I'm sorry you were unable to use the documentation to answer your own question. As Bob's code examples demonstrate I had pointed you in the correct direction.

Comment: @APC no actually you hadn't since the way I had structured my QUERY means that you were suggesting that I continue and go along and say 'EMP' OR 'CLIENT' OR, thanks for your input, but some people learn slowly, OR AND IN may be trivial for some, and difficult for those starting out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
  ORDER BY TABLE_NAME,
           CONSTRAINT_NAME
```

which will let you browse through all constraints in the database.  If you've got a subset of tables you're interested in you can toss in a WHERE clause such as

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('EMP',
                       'CLIENT',
                       'OTHER_TABLE',
                       'OTHER_TABLE2',
                       'YET_ANOTHER_TABLE')
  ORDER BY TABLE_NAME,
           CONSTRAINT_NAME
```

or

```
  ...
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'EMP' OR
        TABLE_NAME = 'CLIENT' OR
        TABLE_NAME = 'OTHER_TABLE' OR
        TABLE_NAME = 'OTHER_TABLE2' OR
        TABLE_NAME = 'YET_ANOTHER_TABLE'
  ...
```

The two WHERE clauses above are equivalent - the first is just a bit more compact.

Share and enjoy.